# Controlling Video with Gestures

Tags: iphone, video, gesture-recognition

I have a video playing a camera rotating around a 3D model. I want to be able to sweep left to right to play the video forwards and right to left to play the video backwards.

Can this be done on iOS 4 and how?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the view that holds the video, and configure it.

Comment: But how do I then manage the speed of the swipe = speed of play, and for the reverse?

Comment: You would have to create a custom gesture recognizer that kept track of swipe velocity, but it might still be easier than a view with a touch handler.

Answer (score 0):

just add a new transparent view on top of your video and catch touch actions in that layer