# Get Speed of UISwipeGestureRecognizer - Custom Gesture Recogniser?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app that plays a video. I want to control the video by Gesture i.e. swipe left-to-right for forwards and right-to-left for backwards.

[I previously asked a question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442372/controlling-video-with-gestures), but that was when the project was but an idea. Now I am to sit down and code the thing myself I have no idea what to do.

The answerer added that I may need to create a custom gesture recogniser to get the speed of the swipe, I wish this speed to affect the speed of the video.

Any ideas how I would go about this?

I've never built or configured a gesture recogniser before so I've no idea how to go about it?

What I really want is a way to handle the begin and end methods. I think I can get a timer running between the two and work out the X & Y to calculate the speed. Any help, code-samples and the like will help.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to calculate the time difference and x-position difference between `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`. Using these two numbers, you can calculate "pixels per second", or similar. You can then use the magnitude of the result to act as the coefficient of the speed of the video.

Comment: that's the kind of thing I want. I'm not sure how to tap into any of the gesture recogniser methods, I'm kinda new to this, how would I get the X and Y coordinates?

Comment: Check out the `UIResponder` documentation for the methods I gave above. Define them in your view controller. The `NSSet` argument is a set of `UITouch` objects which hold location. All you need to do is store the time and x-position in `touchesBegan` and compare them to the ones in `touchesEnded`.

Comment: @danielhanly.com Hey bro,Have you found out how to do this,Please help me

Comment: @NithinMK Have a look at this: http://www.danielhanly.com/blog/tutorial/gesture-controlling-a-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller/